# Commas added to JSON server server-side makes JSON unreadable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, parsing

I'm creating a JSON object like this :

```
public class JsonObject
{
    public string dataCLTotalCount { get; set; }
    public string dataCCTotalCount { get; set; }
}

var Temporary = (from DataItem in DataSource_.Cast<object>()
     select new JsonObject
     {                                 
         dataCCTotalCount = string.Format("{0:n0}", ((long)GetPropertyValue(DataItem, "DataCCTotalCount"))),
         dataCLTotalCount =  string.Format ("{0:n0}", ((long)GetPropertyValue(DataItem, "DataCLTotalCount")))
     }).ToList();
var serialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Temporary);
return serialized;
```

When I try to run that JSON with my client side code (JS) , the commas makes it unreadable , preventing the graphs from displaying the data.

Is `string.Format("{0:n0}" , ...)` is to blame ?

Thanks

Comment: Are the commas separating the decimal part of the numeric values?

Comment: @Gimly : Yeah , like `123454` is `123,454` .

Comment: Why not just serialize it as a raw numeric value and format it for display?

Comment: @Lee Willis: Requirements , it's not me :) , it's them ...

Comment: Since those values are strings the comma should be okay. Can you show a sample of the JSON that you get from this?

Comment: @JonHanna: `"dataTotalCount\":\"455,251\",\"dataCCTotalCount\":`

Comment: Are you sure that your numeric value should be a string? Shouldn't your JSON be something like:

`{"dataTotalCount" : 455251, "dataCCTotalCount" : 4451212}`

Comment: Just knocked up a LINQPad test of your code, and the JSON I get is fine (tested in Chrome console); as Jon Hanna says, the values are serialized as strings so should deserialize fine. Is it definitely deserialization where you are getting the error, not where you are trying to use the result?

Comment: @ron That string you posted in reply to Jon Hanna looks like the JSON string itself has then been serialized again, resulting in an escaped string, NOT an object definition. Is there some later serialization / escaping happening?

Comment: Yes , I have another serialization later , for  `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`

Comment: If you serialize the result of `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize` then you will get an escaped string, which will not resolve to an object on the client, so you will get errors when you try to access the properties.

If I understand what you are doing correctly, you need to change the `RegisterStartupScript` call to not serialize this result.

Comment: I should add that even if this fix gives you a proper object literal, if you need to use those values as numeric, you will need to not have the commas. I have added an answer to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you're using `string.Format` without specifying the cultureinfo. It means that it's taking whatever culture is configured on the server, and it happens that your server is using a language where the decimal separator is a comma.

You can specify `InvariantCulture` in your string.format like so:

```
String.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    "{0:n0}", 
    (long)GetPropertyValue(DataItem, "DataCCTotalCount"));
```

And it should fix the problem.

Edit: Didn't realize from your comment that it was adding the thousand's separator. Adding the InvariantCulture won't fix that. You should specify another numeric format than "N" (Number). You should probably use "F" for fixed point in your case:

```
String.Format(
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
     "{0:F0}",
     (long)GetPropertyValue(DataItem, "DataCCTotalCount"));
```

Comment: `"{0:F0}"` doesn't create commas for me , only `{0:n0}`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. {0:n0} defines that you want to format your output with a "Number" format, which has the thousands separators (which, in your culture is a comma). F doesn't. Does it fix your issue then? Check here for the list of formats: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No , it doesn't ... any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: So, if you put "{0:F0}" you don't have the commas anymore, but your JSon is still not valid?

Comment: If I use `{0:F0}` my JSON is valid , but no commas

Comment: In your question you say that the commas make the JSON unreadable. I've explained how to remove the commas and now you say there are no commas. Can you be more clear about what you want?

Comment: My commas with the `{0:n0}` makes the string with commas however unreadable , but with `{0:F0}` it is readable  however without commas .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77074/discussion-between-gimly-and-ron).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the `JavaScriptSerializer` is to correctly serialize many object types for you; to get a valid JSON numeric you don't need your own string conversion; you don't even need a `(long)` cast as the serializer will determine the type using reflection.

This also means you can eliminate the intermediate `JsonObject` class and use an anonymous type.

```
var Temporary = (from DataItem in DataSource_.Cast<object>()
     select new
     {                                 
         dataCCTotalCount = GetPropertyValue(DataItem, "DataCCTotalCount"),
         dataCLTotalCount =  GetPropertyValue(DataItem, "DataCLTotalCount")
     }).ToList();
```